# Comparison similar to strncmp in objective c

Tags: objective-c, comparison

This is a practical question here : Is it possible to compare two strings character by character ? Just like strncmp in C where you give first string, second string and the number of matching characters that need to be reached to return YES.
Thanks for any answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<[testlength];i++){

if ([@"test" characterAtIndex:i] == 'testSample'){

}

}
```

Comment: Thank :) didn't know character by character comparison worked on a NSString Object. But do you have any clue why they didn't think about implementing a such basic method in their libraries ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to compare NSStrings, depending on what you need exactly:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask;
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)range;
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)range locale:(id)locale;
- (NSComparisonResult)caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCompare:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSComparisonResult)localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)aString;

- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString;
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject;
```

`NSComparisonResult` is a `NSInteger` enum that can be `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame` or `NSOrderedDescending`, which are -1, 0 and 1 respectively.

The closest to `strncmp(s1, s2, n)` would be `[s1 compare:s2 options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, n)]`

Comment: Is this Christmas already :D Thank you ^^i will try it right away.